# Can fonts control the spacing between italic words and non-italic words?

Tags: fonts, kerning

I often see examples where the spacing between an italicized word and a non-italicized word isn't sufficient. For example, in "*Bored* book" the tall thin portion of the d and b get a bit too close in some fonts (e.g. whatever Discord uses).

Is this spacing something that fonts have control over like how they can control kerning around letters or between certain letter pairs?

Comment: Not sure if that's possible TBH.  If it's for use on a web page, you could use [CSS Word Spacing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.php), or in graphic design more generally, some graphic design software has word spacing attributes, or kerning can be done manually.

Comment: @BillyKerr On a website, it'd be more appropriate to use `margin` (probably `margin-inline-end`) on the `<em>` and `<i>` elements, not word spacing, for this use case

Comment: @ZachSaucier - good to know.

Comment: With that being said, if CSS applies `font-style: italic` to some other element, the above would not catch it. So it'd be good to handle this on a font level if possible!